# Getting analytic center manifolds

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems

The center manifold of a degenerate zero of an analytic vector field need not be unique nor analytic.  But say I want it analytic.  Does anyone know of additional conditions to be imposed on the vector field which guarantee that out of the -perhaps many -
center manifolds, one which is analytic can be selected?  Failing general conditions
a rich supply of examples where such a selection is possible might be nice.

This question arose in some N-body research regarding total collision solutions.